# JOOQ after executeInsert(), need to know the auto-generated ID

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jooq

Using JOOQ (with sqlite3).

Have some code that looks like this:
(Modified from example in the docs: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/)

```
// A "mutable" POJO class
public class MyBook {
  public int id;
  public String title;
}

// Create a new POJO instance
MyBook myBook = new MyBook();
// myBook.id = 10; <-- Id is NOT set here because the database auto-generates it
myBook.title = "Animal Farm";

// Load a jOOQ-generated BookRecord from your POJO
BookRecord book = create.newRecord(BOOK, myBook);

// Insert it (explicitly)
create.executeInsert(book);

// What is value of the auto-generated id?
```

At this point, I need to know the auto-generated ID from the database.

- Any ideas on how to get it?
- Or do I need to set the ID before I save it?

Answer (score 2):

Using `executeInsert()` does not seem to get the ID back:

```
// Insert it (explicitly)
create.executeInsert(book);
```

However using `Record.store` does:

```
book.store()
```

Here is how to go from POJO to Record so that the PJO can be stored and then get the updated POJO with the generted ID:

```
// A "mutable" POJO class
public class MyBook {
  public int id;
  public String title;
}

// Create a new POJO instance
MyBook myBook = new MyBook();
// myBook.id = 10; <-- Id is NOT set here because the database auto-generates it
myBook.title = "Animal Farm";

// Load a jOOQ-generated BookRecord from your POJO
BookRecord book = create.newRecord(BOOK, myBook);

// Insert it (implicitly) using the BookRecord instead of create.executeInsert()
book.store();            // <--- THIS IS THE KEY DIFFERENCE

// Get new Book POJO from the BookRecord
MyBook newBook = book.into(MyBook.class);

// This is also a handy function to get the Record as Map, 
//   which is easier to view in the debugger
Map<String, Object> bookMap = book.intoMap();
```

Comment: I am late to comment here.  I only found this Q&A today.  Are you aware of the SQLite function `last_insert_rowid()`?  (Ref: https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)  I don't know your exact table schema, but it _may_ be possible.  You need to experiment a little bit... Using jOOQ, you can do: `select last_insert_rowid()` which will return `SQLDataType.BIGINT` / `long`.